# Google Analytic Embed API chart isn't rendered

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to create a chart using the Google Analytic Embed API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart). Authentication works fine, yet the chart isn't rendered.

This is my code:

```
<html>
...
<body>


<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {


  var CLIENT_ID = '[client id, which I removed for this purpose]';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });


var chart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
  query: {
    'ids': 'ga: [profile id, removed]',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
    'dimensions': 'ga:date',
   'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',

  },
  chart: {
    'type': 'LINE',
    'container': 'line-chart',
    'options': {
      'title': 'Test report',
      }
  }
});

chart.on('success', function(response) {
   response.chart

});

chart.execute();

});

</script>
                    <div id="auth-button"></div>
                    <div id="line-chart" style='width:100%;height:300px;'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would be very grateful, if somebody could take a look at the code and help me.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact code works just fine for me when I use my client ID and view ID.

That leads me to believe you didn't set up your client ID correctly, in which case you should be getting JavaScript errors in the developer console. Did you look there? The most likely problem is you didn't set the correct origins.

Comment: Thanks! My Client ID ist correct and I do not see JavaScript errors. How does your view ID look like? I used "'ids': ga 'UA-XXX-1' (see above) and wonder whether this might be the mistake? Thanks again for your help - hope, I'll get this working...

Comment: That's not the correct way to refer to the `ids` property. I'd recommend taking a look at the [Account Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) tool; it can help you figure out which ID to use in which use-case.

Comment: Thanks again! Really strange - I used the correct id (which is the profile ID) before changing it to "UA - xxxx" - and now just changed back to the correct id. Still, it doesn't work. Could you do my a great favor and post (part) of your code here? I have no clue why the chart isn't rendered since my code above seems correct (as you said, too). Many thanks again for your help!